# Select2 get text onchange -comma seperated

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I use select2 for getting the the values in the select box, but my problem is, I only want to get the first item in the select box the ignore the comma seperated item like this:

```js
$(function() {

  $('.select2').select2({
    theme: "classic",

  }).on('change', function(e) {
    var dataselected = $.map($(".select2 option:selected"), function(el, i) {
      return $(el).text();
    });

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="donut" id="first">donut-milk</option>
  <option value="orange" id="first">orange-milk</option>
</select>
```

This yields to:

```
["donut-milk","orange-milk"]
```

How can I achieve this output:

```
["donut","orange"]
```

Comment: You want to remove the string after `-` of the selected value??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is when you have the text split it from "-" and get the 0th element. That means after you are splitting you have an array.

For an example:

```
  var dataselected = $.map($(".select2 option:selected"),function (el, i){
        var elemText = $(el).text().split('-')[0]; //like this
        return elemText;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the value instead of text content, use [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method or use [`value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/value) property to get the value.

```
var dataselected = $.map($(".select2 option:selected"),function (el, i){
    return  $(el).val();
});
```

```js
$(function() {

  $('.select2').select2({
    theme: "classic",

  }).on('change', function(e) {
    var dataselected = $.map($(".select2 option:selected"), function(el, i) {
      return $(el).val();
    });

    console.log(dataselected);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="donut" id="first">donut-milk</option>
  <option value="orange" id="first">orange-milk</option>
</select>
```

or

```
var dataselected = $.map($(".select2 option:selected"),function (el, i){
    return  el.value;
});
```

```js
$(function() {

  $('.select2').select2({
    theme: "classic",

  }).on('change', function(e) {
    var dataselected = $.map($(".select2 option:selected"), function(el, i) {
      return el.value;
    });

    console.log(dataselected);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="donut" id="first">donut-milk</option>
  <option value="orange" id="first">orange-milk</option>
</select>
```

---

Or simply get the value from the `select` tag.

```
var dataselected = $(".select2").val()
```

As per [jQuery docs of `val()` method](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val):

> When the first element in the collection is a select-multiple (i.e., a select element with the multiple attribute set), .val() returns an array containing the value of each selected option.

---

**FYI :** `id` should be unique in a context so avoid using duplicate id's. For grouping use `class` attribute.

---

**UPDATE :** If you want to extract the first part from the text content(before `-`) then you can do something like this using [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method.

```
var dataselected = $.map($(".select2 option:selected"), function(el, i) {
  return $(el).text().split('-')[0];
  // or
  // return $(el).text().split('-').shift();
});
```

```js
$(function() {

  $('.select2').select2({
    theme: "classic",

  }).on('change', function(e) {
    var dataselected = $.map($(".select2 option:selected"), function(el, i) {
      return $(el).text().split('-')[0];
      // or
      // return $(el).text().split('-').shift();
    });

    console.log(dataselected);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="donut" id="first">donut-milk</option>
  <option value="orange" id="first">orange-milk</option>
</select>
```